# What is the closest equivalent to a Gaussian distribution on a discrete domain?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, distribution-theory

I find the Gaussian distribution easy to comprehend with its two parameters: the mean $\mu$ centres it and the stdev $\sigma$ spreads it. However, what is its closest equivalent on a discrete finite (or semi-finite) domain? It is also important for me to maintain the "parameters" $\sigma$ and $\mu$ on this discretized (and potentially bounded) space since I want to control its **centre** and **spread**.

PS: Going through the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) of discrete probability distributions, some do look like "discretized" Gaussians but their parameters aren't quite the centre and spread used in Gaussians. Examples of this are the Poisson or the [Conway-Maxwell-Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%E2%80%93Maxwell%E2%80%93Poisson_distribution) distributions.

Comment: In theory you want a quadratic log-pmf, but I don't think that gives closed forms for the mean or variance, or for the quadratic's coefficients in terms of them.

Comment: You seem to want the mean and standard deviation to be exact.  Do you have any other constraints, such as support on the non-negative integers?  Otherwise choose a large $n$, let $Y \sim \text{Bin}(n,\frac12)$, and let $X=\mu + \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}(2Y-n)$ so $X$ has a discrete distribution on $n+1$ possible values with the desired mean and standard deviation and a close-to-normal distribution.

Comment: @Henry Regarding the support, I do indeed want to exclude non-negative integers (including zero).

Comment: @Tfovid "exclude"?

Comment: @Henry I meant the probability is zero for negative integers.